# In flutter How to call method in Container on click of button?

Tags: flutter, dart

In My flutter app, I have designed three buttons, now I want to call three methods on click of the buttons.
This is my screen:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1RDF.png)

If i click on View button I want to call `ViewAll()` method. If I click on Rejected button then I want to call `Reject()` method. If I click on Accepted button then I want to call `Accept()` method.

```
This is my code:
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Reallocation", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(height: 5),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Center(
              child: _tags1(context),
              heightFactor: 1.5,
            ),
          ),
         SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Divider(color: Colors.grey)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Center(

              //child: ViewAll(context,resultCheck3),
            )
         )
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
```

This widget for design buttons:

```
 Widget _tags1 (BuildContext context){
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:15.0)),
              Container(
                  child:RaisedButton(
                      shape: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.lightBlue),
                      child: Text("View"),
                      onPressed: (){

                      })
              ),
              Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:25.0)),
              Container(

                  child:RaisedButton(
                      shape: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.lightBlue),
                      child: Text("Rejected"),
                      onPressed: (){
                        // some code here
                      })
              ),
              Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
              Container(
                  child:RaisedButton(
                      shape: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.lightBlue),
                      child: Text("Accepted"),
                      onPressed: (){
                        // some code here
                      })
              )
            ],
          )

        ],
      ),
    );
}
```

Now i have called `ViewAll()` method directly in Body without on click.
I have 3 different buttons and 3 different methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call the method in `onPressed` method of the `RaisedButton`.

```
Container(
   child:RaisedButton(
   shape: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.lightBlue),
   child: Text("Rejected"),
   onPressed: Rejected // this will the method for your rejected Button
)
```

This is just an example, You will have to figure out by yourself for the desired output you want. It's little difficult to give the exact solution.

Example:

```
int _viewFlag = 1;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Reallocation", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(height: 5),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Center(
              child: _tags1(context),
              heightFactor: 1.5,
            ),
          ),
         SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Divider(color: Colors.grey)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: _viewFlag == 1 ? Center(
              child: ViewAll(context,resultCheck3),
            ) : _viewFlag == 2 ? Center(
              child: RejectAll(context,resultCheck3),
            ) : Center(
              child: AcceptAll(context,resultCheck3),
            )
         )
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: If i click on reject button then where Rejected() methods data will be show?

Comment: because i want to show reject() methods data in body

Comment: You might have done that part so you only you know where the data will be shown. Because I don't know what is the code in your reject button. and I have done this for only one button. You have to do the same way for other buttons with their respective methods.

Comment: if click on reject button then data will be show here                     
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Center(
           child: Reject(context,resultCheck3), ). How to show data here on Click of button

Comment: You can use a flag for that purpose. and based on the flag and button click you can show the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call your method in => "on pressed(){}".
Example:

```
{ _yourMethod(){
  // some code in here...
}
//...

FlatButton(
 onPressed: _yourMethod,
 child: const Text('Sign In',
   style: TextStyle(
     color: Colors.white,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
   ),
 ),
 color: Colors.red,
),
```